# filter column based on date range

Tags: mysql, sql, date, select, where-clause

I need to filter a column containing the time and date by a date range.
I just want to see the values which have been recorded for a month from the present day.(from 2016-06-21 to 2016-07-21)
The date format in the Column is YYYY-mm-dd HH:mm:ss
Some of the data in the column looks like this:

```
2016-07-01 13:38:04
2016-07-01 12:52:41
2016-07-01 12:52:41
2015-05-30 13:04:42
2015-05-30 13:04:42
2016-06-29 10:23:39
2016-06-29 10:23:39
2016-06-29 09:49:43
2015-05-29 09:49:20
2015-05-28 15:05:11
2016-05-28 15:04:46
2016-06-28 15:00:43
2016-05-30 11:33:42
2016-05-30 11:30:53
2015-05-02 09:54:34
```

Comment: Plz add some of the table rows you meant in your question. So that it helps to understand the requirement well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where col >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 month);
```

This should work whether your column is stored as a string or a `datetime`, because the format is readily converted to a `datetime`.  However, you should use the native types for dates and times, rathe than strings.

Comment: is date_sub a built in function for SQL 2014?

Comment: @UTTARA . . . No, it is a function in MySQL which is how the question is tagged.

Answer (score 0):

Here is somewhat you can use:-

```
SELECT * 
 FROM drange_table 
 Where date_range_column between DATE_SUB(curdate(), interval 1 month) and curdate()
```